# Displaying parsed values from webservice in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, uitableview

I'm calling a webservice in `viewDidLoad` method of tableViewcontroller class and parsing the data in another class as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dataWebService = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSString *authString = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",@"admin", @"admin"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64Encoding];        


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.16.3.47:8980/opennms/rest/alarms?limit=5"]] retain];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",authString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [dataWebService setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [dataWebService appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
     NSLog(@"Eror during connection: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    AlarmWSParse* alarmParser = [[AlarmWSParse alloc]init];

    severity = [alarmParser xmlParser:responseString];

    NSLog(@"no of elements in array %d",[severity count]);

    NSLog(@"Back to Alarm List View controller and severtiy array is %@",severity);
}
```

and then setting this severity array value in table cell as

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [severity count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString* cellValue = [severity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"cellvalue %@",cellValue);
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

The table remains empty but `NSLog` displays all the data correctly.

Also, after the web service is called and parsed, my app crashes in simulator without any error msg in debugger.

How do I display these values in array to tableview?

Guess what.. the nslog message for cellValue or any other nslog msg i include in `tabelView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` does not gets printed in console..

Here is the my console view

```
[Session started at 2011-12-22 11:12:07 +0530.]
2011-12-22 11:12:09.358 WebServiceTab[11815:207] do while loopalarm
2011-12-22 11:12:09.359 WebServiceTab[11815:207] severity is MAJOR
2011-12-22 11:12:09.359 WebServiceTab[11815:207] do while loopalarm
2011-12-22 11:12:09.359 WebServiceTab[11815:207] severity is MAJOR
2011-12-22 11:12:09.360 WebServiceTab[11815:207] do while loopalarm
2011-12-22 11:12:09.360 WebServiceTab[11815:207] severity is MAJOR
2011-12-22 11:12:09.360 WebServiceTab[11815:207] do while loopalarm
2011-12-22 11:12:09.360 WebServiceTab[11815:207] severity is MINOR
2011-12-22 11:12:09.361 WebServiceTab[11815:207] do while loopalarm
2011-12-22 11:12:09.361 WebServiceTab[11815:207] severity is MAJOR
2011-12-22 11:12:09.361 WebServiceTab[11815:207] no of elements in array 5
2011-12-22 11:12:09.362 WebServiceTab[11815:207] Back to Alarm List View controller and severtiy array is (
    MAJOR,
    MAJOR,
    MAJOR,
    MINOR,
    MAJOR
)
```

Iam sharing few source code files here: https://gist.github.com/fce50a3c4d20cb9c4677
Kindly have a look if you can find any bugs. My app seems like it was made to crash only:(

Comment: I would be thankful if somebody could edit the code section of my question as its not displayed in easily understandable colorful manner

Comment: Please reformat. It's horrible to read :)

Comment: i tried but i donot know much how to edit it.

Comment: @TechnocraT: Highlight the code and press the `{}` button.

Comment: the - symbol before method names turned to bullets and hence rest of the code turned that way..

Comment: looks awesome, do we now understand the question.Thanks for editing.. Awaiting the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether [severity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] returns you NSString , I think it should be some thing else

```
 NSString* cellValue = [severity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And as well as try [tableView reloadData] as mentioned by the.evangelist

Comment: As u can see the edited question, the cellValue just doen not get printed in console.. Any solution??

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",severity); can you add this in your code a get me the console data, so that I can help you in this, just want to know the data in severity

Comment: As you can see in my edited question, the last values are output of severity in console.

Comment: [self.tableview reloadData]; in - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection function at the last line because it reloads the data once you received the complete data, if you have same command some where else just remove it

Comment: Done it still the app crashes without displaying any data in table.Also i'm hosting few of the source code files,please have a look    if it could be helpful. https://gist.github.com/fce50a3c4d20cb9c4677

Comment: NSString* cellValue = [test objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; it should be NSString* cellValue = [severity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; since severity is there variable where you set the data

Comment: well its the same, i forgot to replace it with severity after testing with the array test.

Comment: Can you send me the crash log

Comment: included the console log along with source code at the bottom.

Comment: Issue is you didn't set datasource and delegate for UITableview

Comment: change this code in @interface AlarmListViewController : UITableViewController 
 <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

Comment: [tableView setDelegate:self];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];
add it viewDidload of AlarmListViewController

Comment: @TechnocraT did adding UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate solve your issue?

Comment: Not yet.. Error:tableView undeclared.I have tried self.tableView.Doing  that clears the error but app still crashes with the same output..

Answer (score 1):

Try `[tableView reloadData]` after you are done with parsing in `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

Comment: As i mentioned the application keeps on crashing after the data is parsed.Also i've tried [self.tableView reloadData]; in conncectionDidFinishLoading method.But dont know whats happening as app crashes..

Comment: 1. Comment the line "[connection release];" in connectionDidFinishLoading. 2. Read the parser code to see if you are parsing the returned data correctly, ie no memory leaks etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code table reload issue. Please reload table after getting response from webservice.

Answer (score 0):

i face many time this problem, and i solved by this method.

1) used temporary array to save the parsing data
2) allocate your table array
3) the temporary array data added to your array which is used in table array
4) reload your table

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[dataWebService appendData:data];
[self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Try this may be it will work....

EDIT:

For the reason of your crash i think you did not `retain` your `NSMutableArray` severity. In viewDidLoad after try that....

```
[[severity alloc] init];
[severity retain];
```

Comment: Doesn't work dude.. My app crashes after displaying values of array object in nslog..

Comment: Still the same, though i have edited as u mentioned with [[severity alloc]init];
 [severity retain]; after [super viewDidLoad];

Comment: without  severity just see that is your cell text are printing or not just for test see that..... `cell.textLabel.text = @"this text for cell";` if not printing then there is a problem in your tableview.then check have you called your tableview delegate and datasource perfectly or not.If any question then don't hesitate just ask me...

Comment: it doen't print the text but if i use a new test array and add objects explicidly then give [test count] it works fine.. if its severity it doesn't enter the rowAtIndexPath.. method

Comment: what do you want to say actually?

Comment: I meant i have shared the source code at https://gist.github.com/fce50a3c4d20cb9c4677 for a broad view of the problem.

Comment: @TechnocraT  Can you please post your complete project file directory, so that I can Compile and loook into